# Как поочерёдно вставлять каждое число из списка?

Tags: python-3.7

Допустим у меня есть сайт https://a5.ttap.org в котором меняется лишь одно число  значение x. Как мне сделать подбор каждого числа из списка(необязательно либо от 1 до 5)?

```
data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
url = f'https://a{x}.ttap.org/` # поочерёдно вставлять значения из списка

response = requests.get(url)

if response == 200:
    print("It's working")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здесь, просто, нужно перебрать каждую цифру через for

```
for i in range(1, 6):
   url = f'https://a{i}.ttap.org/'
   response = requests.get(url).status_code

   if response is 200:
      print("It's working")
      break
```